# Header fixed as footer

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jua3j/9/) with header, content and footer.

You can see that CSS for header and footer are analogical. Footer behaves as I want but
header collides with text when scrolling.

Do you know what is wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your content div is located after the header, its z-index is "higher" by default, so it will be "on top" of your header when you scroll.

Add

```
z-index:1000;
```

to your header css.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a matter of adding a `z-index` value on `#header`.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Jua3j/22](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/Jua3j/22/)**

Also, don't forget to give `#content` enough `padding-bottom` to clear the height of `#footer`.